# How to convert string to byte arrays?

Tags: python

How can I convert a string to its byte value? I have a string `"hello"` and I want to change is to something like `"/x68..."`.

Comment: You realize that it's all just bits and bytes at the lowest level and that the strings `"hello"` and `"\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"` are identical (unless you escape the backslashes instead of using them for hex escapes)?

Comment: Yes I know. I just want to export into some array in such low level.

Comment: This makes no sense, what do you _actually_ want to do? (This is just some intermediate step you think you need to do)

Comment: I want to change all what is in file (String) into byte array.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? It's worth noting that the `str` type in Python basically *is* just a set of bytes (meaning that it doesn't have a representation, like Unicode, attached and can just be an arbitrary sequence of bytes, despite its name).

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488297/) question.

Comment: @delnan you forgot a NULL character.

Comment: We should add: if you're using Python 3, `str` is unicode. To convert it to bytes, do `s.encode()` (you can also specify what character encoding you want, otherwise it will use UTF-8).

Comment: @Time Machine: No. Python doesn't use `NUL`-terminated strings. And as far as I know, even C string literals get it automatically.

Comment: Yes, they get them automatically in C, unlees you explicitly specify an **array** with brackets and comma's.

Comment: For those who are wondering why you would want to do this: I found this to be useful for parsing binary data read using pySerial.

Answer (score 33):

Python 2.6 and later have a [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bytearray) type which may be what you're looking for. Unlike strings, it is mutable, i.e., you can change individual bytes "in place" rather than having to create a whole new string. It has a nice mix of the features of lists and strings. And it also makes your intent clear, that you are working with arbitrary bytes rather than text.

Comment: quote "I want to change all what is in file (String) into byte array. " .. @kindall's answer does exactly that. +1 for bytearray()

Comment: `list(bytearray("hello"))`

Comment: I did some speed testing and `list(bytearray("hello"))` is faster than `map(ord, "hello")`

Comment: Not converting it to a list (leaving it as a `bytearray`) is generally even faster!

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps you want this (Python 2):

```
>>> map(ord,'hello')
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

For a Unicode string this would return Unicode code points:

```
>>> map(ord,u'Hello, 马克')
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 39532, 20811]
```

But encode it to get byte values for the encoding:

```
>>> map(ord,u'Hello, 马克'.encode('chinese'))
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 194, 237, 191, 203]
>>> map(ord,u'Hello, 马克'.encode('utf8'))
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 233, 169, 172, 229, 133, 139]
```

Comment: Note that this will not return "byte" values for non-ASCII characters, because ord will return something bigger than 0xFF.

Comment: @user100464, not for a byte string, which the above is for Python 2 (`map` doesn't return a list in Python 3).  A byte can't be above 0xFF.  Also, non-ASCII is above 0x7F, not 0xFF :)

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get hexadecimal string representation you could do:

```
"hello".encode("hex") # '68656c6c6f'
```

And to meet your reference representation (don't take it seriously, guess this is ***not what you really want***):

```
"".join(["/x%02x" % ord(c) for c in "hello"]) # '/x68/x65/x6c/x6c/x6f'
```